# Getting sorted state of p:dataTable in backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

*I need get sorted data list of datatable from backing bean*

I tried to get list as below after performing sort operation,

```
public class PmoRequestService{

    List<RequestEntity> requestList;

    public void seeListAfterOrdering(){
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("entities");

        List<RequestEntity> newList = (List<RequestEntity>)dataTable.getValue();

    }

    //getters - setters
}
```

but this gives the same list when datatable is initialized (without sorting). I mean `newList` and `requestList` have the same data order and they are not affected from sorting.

**EDIT:**

```
<p:dataTable id="entities" widgetVar="cellRequest" 
    var="entityVar"
    value="#{pmoRequestService.requestList}"
    rowKey="#{entityVar.cdProcess}"
    selection="#{pmoRequestService.selectedRequest}"
    draggableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true" paginator="true"
    editable="true" editMode="cell" rows="17"
    sortMode="multiple" selectionMode="single" >

... Some columns here

<!--this is unique identifier column for each row-->
<p:column headerText="Request Id" width="60"
        sortBy="#{entityVar.cdProcess}" filterBy="#{entityVar.cdProcess}"
        filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{entityVar.cdProcess}" />
</p:column> 

...Some columns here

</p:dataTable>
```

**EDIT:**

I'm using PF version 5

Comment: Which PF version? When exactly are you executing that piece of code? This works for me with PF5 and using `requestList` property directly during invoke application phase without that unnecessary grabbing of the whole component.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: You forgot to answer the other question.

Comment: I need get sorted data list of datatable in backing bean, rigth after user perform sorting operation.

Comment: Well, it works for me by just accessing `requestList` directly. Perhaps you're doing more in the getter method than only returning `requestList`?